# There are 2 networking component installed on node master, Weave and Calico. how can I completely remove Calico from my kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, calico

Weave has overlap with host's IP address and its pod stuck in **CrashLoopBackOff** state. There is a need to remove Calico first as I have no clue about working 2 Networking module on master!

```
emo@master:~$ sudo kubectl get pod -A
NAMESPACE         NAME                              READY   STATUS              RESTARTS        AGE
kube-system       coredns-64897985d-dw6ch           0/1     ContainerCreating   0               
kube-system       coredns-64897985d-xr6br           0/1     ContainerCreating   0               
kube-system       etcd-master                       1/1     Running             26 (14m ago)    
kube-system       kube-apiserver-master             1/1     Running             26 (12m ago)    
kube-system       kube-controller-manager-master    1/1     Running             4 (20m ago)     
kube-system       kube-proxy-g98ph                  1/1     Running             3 (20m ago)     
kube-system       kube-scheduler-master             1/1     Running             4 (20m ago)     
kube-system       weave-net-56n8k                   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff    76 (54s ago)    
tigera-operator   tigera-operator-b876f5799-sqzf9   1/1     Running             6 (5m57s ago)
```

master:

```
emo@master:~$ kubectl get node -o wide
NAME     STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master   Ready    control-plane,master   6d19h   v1.23.5   192.168.71.132   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS   5.4.0-81-generic   containerd://1.5.5
```

Comment: Are you using `kubeadm` to bootstrap your cluster?

Comment: yes i do, i use ```kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr``` to deploy my cluster and its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to re-build your cluster after cleaning it up.

First, run `kubectl delete` for all the manifests you have applied to configure `calico` and `weave`. (e.g. kubectl delete -f https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/manifests/tigera-operator.yaml)

Then run `kubeadm reset` and run `/etc/cni/net.d/` to delete all of your cni configurations. After that, you also need to reboot the server to delete some old records of `ip link`, or manually remove them by `ip link delete {name}`.

Now the new installation should be done well.